# Hide Standard Progress Bar when openning/saving excel file with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problems when I use Workbook.Open or Workbook.close savechanges:: true.

Sometimes, the macro the standard progress bar stucks and I have to manually cancel it. Despite of this, the excel file still opens.

The same happens when I save some files. It just stucks in the progress bar, while the files is being saved. It always saves the file, but the excel progress bar just stucks.

I have no idea why it does that, because it just happen sometimes.

I would like to test if I hide this standard progress bar, it could work.

Anybody could give me some help?

[image]

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=diretorio & arquivo, ReadOnly:=True 'The progress bar stucks in here
Windows(arquivo).Activate
Sheets(Analista_SIOF).Select
solicitante = Application.Proper(ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last author"))
Workbooks(arquivo).Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: where is your code that calls the progress bar?

Comment: It doesn't, It seems an Excel standard. Whenever It executes the Workbooks.Open or .Close (savechanges true) this progress bar appears.

Comment: You are seeing that progressbar becuase you are saving to a network drive. You can disable these progressbars by disabling the robustified UNC by setting the `DisableRobustifiedUNC` key in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options` to `0`.

Comment: BTW if you do not see that key then you can manually add it... But remember if you modify the registry incorrectly, windows may become unstable.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to do it. How could I add it? I can't see an option for that.

Comment: `I don't think I'm allowed to do it.` If it is a work laptop then maybe yes, you will not be able to edit the registry. `How could I add it? I can't see an option for that.` That means you have not worked with registry before. In that case I would recommend that you do not tinker with it :)

Comment: Thanks o lot, @SiddharthRout. I'm gonna try an alternative,